# Вывод новостей в таблицу используя DLE

Tags: css, dle

Есть шаблон кратких новостей short_news
там выводятся новости по порядку блочно в зависимости от даты.

Возможно ли как нибудь сделать табличный вывод новостей?

Пример (как делает движок)

```
News 1
News 2
News 3
News 4
```

(как хочу я)

```
News 1 News 2
News 3 News 4
```

Код шаблона short_news

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-top:20px;">
    [xfvalue_pic]
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <h3><a href="{full-link}">{title}</a></h3>
    {short-story}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-xs-6" style="margin-top:20px;">
[xfvalue_pic]
<h3><a href="{full-link}">{title}</a></h3>
{short-story}
</div>
```